# how to run docker Image assuming an IAM role on local machine?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-iam

I am working with docker
I am provided a docker image which compiles and runs fine
the application uses Amazon client to interact services like S3 , SNS , SQS .

the moment the application tries to load the client it fails with error

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@17bf085: profile file cannot be null, com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@24117d53: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
```

I have tested on cli that application local IAM configuration is correct
get caller identity on console

`aws sts get-caller-identity`

output

```
{
    "Account": "xxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "UserId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:xxxxxxxx-session-1562266255", 
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::342484191705:assumed-role/abc-abc-abc-abc/xxxxxxxx-session-1562266255"
}
```

so the IAM role is assumed correctly on local machine , 
running unit test and integration test on local machine also assume the IAM role perfectly .

I am running the docker image by command

`docker run -it --rm -e "JPDA_ADDRESS=*:8000" -e "JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket" -p 5033:8000 -p 6060:6033 --memory 1300M --log-driver json-file --log-opt "max-size=1g" docker-image-arn dev`

the image runs but fails all operation where it has to assume IAM role and interact with AWS services .

what is missing ?

how to make application within the container use the IAM role ?

Comment: "profile file cannot be null" could indicate a problem, what if you provide an AWS_PROFILE in the environment?

Comment: It would be much easier to run images with AWS ECS (EC2 launch type). "IAM roles for tasks" - is a built-in ECS feature you'll need to implement if you want to do it without ECS. This might be helpful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/windows_task_IAM_roles.html

Comment: I was able to run aws application inside a container and assume role (using EC2 InstanceRoleProfile) I need more information. In the container can you try pinging 169.254.169.254. Maybe there is a config somewhere in your code that override the assume role? in your java library force com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentials to use this auth method